# Using Javascript Geolocation API, SyntaxError: Unexpected Identifier in Chrome's Javascript console

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-chrome, geolocation

I am trying to get Location of user via javascript Geolocation API,  and show a static image of the map using google maps API, but when I tried to run the script in a webpage, it didn't work,In chrome's javascript console, it says  "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier". 
     I am a bit confused because, there are no misplaced or extra semicolons. Here's the javascript code :

```
    var button = document.querySelector("#button");
    var output = document.querySelector("#output");

    window.onload = init;
    function init(){
        button.addEventListener('click',getPosition,false);
    }
    function getPosition(evt){
        var pos = navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition,onError,{enableHighAccuracy:true,maximamAge:2000});
        console.log(pos);
    }
    function showPosition(position){
        output.innerHTML = "Your Current position is <br/> Latitude : "+position.coords.latitude+" ,  Longitude : "+position.coords.longitude;
        var latlon = position.coords.latitude+","+position.coords.longitude;
        var img_url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center="+latlon+"&zoom=14&size=400x300&sensor=false";
        document.getElementById("mapholder").innerHTML = "<img src='"+img_url+"' />";
    }
    function onError(){
        output.innerHTML = "Something is wrong with your browser";
    }
```

When I checked this code on JSLint it says "Unexpected character ';' ". I tried a lot but I am unble to find what's causing the problem. Please help me with that, Any type of suggestions are also welcome.

Comment: the code you posted passes jslint just fine

Answer (score 2):

Rows 15 and 16 end with wrong encoded semicolons, I replaced them with "normal" ones and it works.

Comment: This is the fiddle with your code: https://jsfiddle.net/ueon5xme/ It triggers the error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL", now replace the semicolons at the end of rows 21 and 22 and it will work :D

Comment: They seem to be unicode characters "U+037E" corresponding to "greek question mark"...